# type-stability issue when a function adds a dimension to the input argument

Tags: types, julia, generic-programming

I have a function with returns an array of the same element-type than the input array but with an additional dimension. 
Here is a simple example:

```
function myfun(a::Array{T,N}) where {T,N}
   b = Array{T,N+1}(size(a)...,2)
   b[:] = 42
   return b
end
```

When this function is called on a 2x2 arrays, it returns an 2x2x2 array.

```
myfun(zeros(2,2))
2×2×2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 42.0  42.0
 42.0  42.0

[:, :, 2] =
 42.0  42.0
 42.0  42.0
```

However, this function is not type-stable. According to `@code_warntype`, `b` is of type `Any`.

Even with type-annotation on `b`, the result is not type-stable
with respect to the number of dimensions:

```
function myfun(a::Array{T,N}) where {T,N}
      b = Array{T,N+1}(size(a)...,2) :: Array{T,N+1}
      b[:] = T(42)
      return b
end
```

`@code_warntype myfun(zeros(2,2))` returns now `Array{Float64,_} where _` for the type of  `b`. Should Julia not be able to figure out that the number of dimensions is 3 when the input argument has 2 dimensions?

I am using julia 0.6.2 (on linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the fact that the constructor(`Array{T,N+1}(size(a)...,2)`) is executed at runtime, you can use [@generated functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1) to precompute `N` at compile time:

```
julia> @generated function myfun(a::Array{T,N}) where {T,N}
           NN = N+1
           quote 
               b = Array{$T,$NN}(size(a)...,2)
               b[:] = 42
               return b
           end
       end
myfun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype myfun(zeros(2,2))
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  a::Array{Float64,2}
  b::Array{Float64,3}

Body:
  begin  # line 2:
      # meta: location REPL[1] # line 4:
      SSAValue(2) = (Base.arraysize)(a::Array{Float64,2}, 1)::Int64
      SSAValue(1) = (Base.arraysize)(a::Array{Float64,2}, 2)::Int64
      b::Array{Float64,3} = $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_3d), Array{Float64,3}, svec(Any, Int64, Int64, Int64), Array{Float64,3}, 0, SSAValue(2), 0, SSAValue(1), 0, :($(QuoteNode(2))), 0)) # line 5:
      $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for fill!(::Array{Float64,3}, ::Int64), :(Base.fill!), :(b), 42))
      # meta: pop location
      return b::Array{Float64,3}
  end::Array{Float64,3}

julia> myfun(zeros(2,2))
2×2×2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 42.0  42.0
 42.0  42.0

[:, :, 2] =
 42.0  42.0
 42.0  42.0
```